# SQL Query returning all table columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
query.Connection = dbconn;
try {
    query.CommandText = "SELECT email,LastSync FROM users WHERE email IN ('alexander@contoso.com')";
    sdr = query.ExecuteReader();
    while(sdr.Read()) if(!sdr.IsDBNull(1)) syncedUsers.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
    sdr.Close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.Log(e.Message);
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    if(sdr!=null) for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        fields.Add(sdr.GetName(i));
    }
    logger.Log(String.Join(",",fields));
}
```

This sometimes (not always) throws the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

and the one time that I looked, the logging then contained a list of **all** fields of the table, not only the two requested fields:

```
id,email,LastSync,...
```

although the query is about two columns only. id is an int, email is a string, so I assume that the error is thrown in `GetString(0)`. The error is not reliably reproducible, I did not yet get it while VS debugging was enabled.

Now, as long as that reader is open, the field list cannot change, or so I think. Is it possible under certain circumstances that the SQL Server returns more fields than I requested?

It is a SQL Server Express 2012.

I know that this can be "solved" by using column names instead of indexes, but before I do, I want to make sure that this is really the issue. I cannot reproduce the issue across all machines I deployed the code to, only certain machines seem to be affected (it doesn't seem to depend on the # of cores available to the machine, nor on the operating system or the .NET version)

EDIT: I now have the same problem when using `ExecuteScalar()`, on the same table. Doesn't happen with other tables, as far as I can see. I try to get a string using the query

```
SELECT displayName FROM users WHERE email=@email
```

using `ExecuteScalar()`, and sometimes the result is `4`, which is the id of the row I requested. So it seems to get the right row, but not the right columns.

This is really weird!

Comment: I would start to add a using around that sdr and declaring it as a local variable on the spot where you are calling ExecuteReader. Some threading issues at work here?

Comment: Where does it throw the error?

Comment: @MarcelTheis Not completely sure, but added an educated guess.

Comment: Add the e.stacktrace and or e.targetsite to your log to find the exact position of the exception

Comment: So if you hit the exception, the datareader is still open, it´s only a cast problem. Try to get the value (sdr.getvalue(0)) in the exception handling to find out, what went wrong.